# Django vs Flask - Which framework is more powerful considering I want to design an end to end IOT solution

Tags: python

Planning to build an end to end IOT application. I know that we can do it using Django and Flask. Which one is a better choice and how it is better?

Comment: If you create a complex project then I think django is the right choice. Me I usualy use flask în combination with other backend languages

Answer (score 1):

I was in your position 2 months ago. Let me save you some trouble.

Flask may seem the more flexible or direct path as it is easy to have something up and running in moments. Whereas Django, at times, can feel like an entirely different language, and takes much more time and effort to get running. Still, the problem lies in getting everything to play nicely with flask and other packages. This will be tricky and Django shines in this area. Once the project is rolling, it just works, and generally continues to do so unless the packages utilized in your app become deprecated or you break it.

Both are viable but any project of scale will be better off being maintained by Django while you focus on implementation. Good luck.